Как реализовать анти спам систему командами в aiogram используя middleware?
Как реализовать анти спам систему командами в aiogram используя middleware? В интернете мало информации на этот счет. В документации aiogram был код анти спама, но из за миграции с aiogram 2 на aiogram 3 код полностью бесполезный.

Сколько не смотрю ваши вопросы, у вас везде "мало информации на этот счёт". Писать код здесь за вас никто не будет. Покажите ваше решение, что вы сделали, что конкретно не получилось?

@BenPuls Везде это два вопроса? Наверное плохо смотрите)

@BenPuls хах, да, я спрашивал "как это реализовать", а не "Напишите за меня код пожалуйста". Я уже смог это сделать, так что не беспокойтесь.
